# How to detect the press of the back button in Cardboard view?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm using Android 5.6 with native support for Cardboard.

I need to get callbacks from the [back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iykdl.jpg) in the Cardboard view.

Before the native implementation I used to do:

```html
 void Update()
    {
        if(GvrViewer.Instance.BackButtonPressed)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
```

Right now I have no idea how to get the back button pressed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Back button on android is mapped to Escape key in Unity. Just use

`Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)`